# Cannot debug on iPhone5 with Xcode 4.6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

All,

I have just got an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.1. I'm trying to run my app on it with my Xcode 4.6.1. I have made sure that the provisioning profile has the device included, but still cannot run on the device

[image]

even though that the Organizer's window shows a green light:

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I also tried setting SDK to be under 6.0, but doesn't help.

[image]

Base SDK is 6.1:

[image]

Found my solution, gotta change deployment target from here (as opposed to the Document Versioning shown before:

[image]

Comment: I am assuming you are building using the 6.0 sdk?

Comment: I think so. Please see my added image. Did I do it right?

Comment: What is your Base SDK?

Comment: Base SDK is 6.1 as I can see on Build Setting

Comment: Why don't you test it with `Xcode-5` with deployment target 6.0 ?

Comment: try making the base SDK 6.0, not 6.1

Comment: @MZimmerman6Yes, I changed that in Deployment Target and works now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try Xcode 4.6.3. 2) Open Xcode 5 and it's organizer until the green light in Xcode 5 comes on for the device, the close Xcode 5 and open Xcode 4.

Comment: It enables your device to be recognized by Xcode 4 as a development device.  Xcode 4 doesn't know iOS 7, so it won't recognize it, though I find it interesting that it shows a green light.  You usually need to open the device through the organizer on Xcode 5 first then Xcode 4 recognizes it (at least Xcode 4.6.3)

Comment: hmm I would not think that opening in multiple version would make a difference. Since they are separate applications. Never tried though